# Issue getting errorCallback from IPromise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm working with an existing `TypeScript` method and I'm struggling to get the `errorCallback` value from the promise. The Interface looks like the following from the Type Definition file for Angular:

```
interface IPromise<T> {
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IHttpPromise<TResult>, errorCallback?: (reason: any) => any, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<TResult>, errorCallback?: (reason: any) => any, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => TResult, errorCallback?: (reason: any) => TResult, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
```

The `TypeScript` method I'm working with calls a service and the promise uses the return (this works):

```
public loadSavedLogin(): ng.IPromise<MyApp.Models.User> {
   return this._myAppService.getUser(this.savedUserId).then((result: MyApp.Models.User) => {
       if (result) {
          this.userId = result.UserID;
          this.userName = result.UserName;
        }
        return result;
     });
}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to get the `errorCallback` value. If I place a comma after `.then((result: MyApp.Models.User)`, I see Intellisense showing me the `errorCallback` parameter, but I just can't get any of the syntax working. In raw `JS`, I'd have a comma at the end with another function accepting the error value, but I'm not sure with this interface how to get the error returned.

How do I modify the function to get the error value if the service call returns one using `IPromise`?

Comment: how do you write when its not working? The errorCallback should be after the "}" that ends the successCallback.

Comment: @Gustav - As Steve suspected and was correct I did not have the correct return type in the error function when I had previously added the error function after the `}`. That's why I couldn't get it to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified example to help you out.

```
class Test {
    public _test: ng.IPromise<string>;

    // This method has a return type of ng.IPromise<string>
    // You must return a value of this type.
    public example(): ng.IPromise<string> {
        return this._test.then(
            // Success
            // Must return a string to be compatible with
            // the ng.IPromise<string> return type
            (val) => {
                alert('Success');
                return val;
            },
            // Error 
            // Should also return a string to be
            // compatible with the return type
            (reason) => {
                alert('Error: ' + reason);
                return '';
            });
    }
}
```

Because the `example` method return type is `ng.IPromise<string>`, the success function and the error function in the `then` method must return a `string` in order for the types to all match up.

In your case, they should return an instance of an `MyApp.Models.User`.

I suspect in your `error` function you weren't returning a value - but this makes the best common type between the success and error function `void`.

Further example... using just an array to show best common types when using functions:

```
var example = [
    (input: string) => { return 'String'; },
    (input: string) => { console.log(input); }
];
```

The best common type used in this example is `(input: string) => void`. Seems strange - but it actually makes sense. If you call the functions in this array, don't expect to get a return value.

So just make sure your success and error functions have the same return type and all the types will match up for you.

```
public loadSavedLogin(): ng.IPromise<MyApp.Models.User> {
    return this._myAppService.getUser(this.savedUserId).then(
        (result: MyApp.Models.User) => {
            if (result) {
                this.userId = result.UserID;
                this.userName = result.UserName;
            }
            return result;
        },
        (reason: string) => {
            return <MyApp.Models.User> null;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `I suspect in your error function you weren't returning a value` this was spot on and you were 100% right. I had tried that syntax previously but since I was returning the proper value it was not compiling. Super helpful and THANK YOU for the extended example. I see it much better.

Comment: The small issue now that this all _works_ is I realize an upstream `JS` promise had separate logic already handling the error. Now that I added the working code from your sample to handle other logic I needed, it seems I've disrupted the flow. Simply returning the error object did not work. How do I in essence re-throw the exception in its original pristine state so that upstream logic is unaffected? (I don't want to _chain_ together questions here so if not a quick answer, I can open another question)

Comment: To re-throw, you can use `(reason: string) => { throw reason; }` or `(reason: string) => { throw new Error(reason); }` - although re-throwing can affect your stack trace.

Comment: This actually worked. However, I _still_ was required to have a return even though I always throw the error. So I end up having `throw error; return error;` This works perfectly, but the code seems bad. The `return` statement can never be hit because of the `throw` before it, yet the `return` is required due to the `IPromise` interface. Is there a better way to do this; have both a `return` and `throw` in that new `error` function? Maybe a `try-catch-finally` with the return in the `finally` and the `throw` in the catch?

Comment: Sorry meant, `try-catch-finally` with the `return` in the `try` and the `throw` in the `finally`?